# react redux fetch after authorized

Tags: reactjs, redux

I need to load some initial data from an API into redux. The user must be authorized in order to hit the API. The user is authorized through an oauth process - sent to an external login and sent to a callback URL, and the token is saved to localstorage, and the authorization status is stored in the redux store.

The authorization status is hydrated as [preloaded state](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/initializing-state) when I configure the redux store.

When a user first loads the application, they

- may already be authorized (have a valid saved token), or
- may need to authorized (don't have a valid saved token).

I'd like to have the initial fetch code in one place. I could just call "fetchTodos" as needed, but I'd have to do this
on init and on loginCallback
. 
All I have come up with is just to make a component to wrap the application, just to load this data, but it seems kind of global and hacky.

```
const LoadTodosWrapper = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const authorized = useSelector(getAuthorized());
  useEffect(() => {
    if(authorized) {
      dispatch(fetchTodos());
    }
  }, [authorized]);
  return <App />;
}
```

Is there a better pattern to fetch initial data, *after the user has been verified to be authorized*?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a strategy I follow for my apps and seems like it fits your case too.

1 - You should have a wrapper component that wraps everything else for your app. It could be your App component that renders all of your routes etc.

2 - Then this component should have two pieces of state to control this strategy.

One is loading. `const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)`

Another is loggedIn. `const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(false)`

3 - Then what you do is:

In your `componentDidMount` (or the corresponding useEffect version), you should check if the user has a token, if not, set loading to false.
If user has a token, then make a request to validate the token.
For success or failure, set loggedIn and set loading to false.

4 - In your render, if loading is `true`, show a loading page and render nothing else.

5 - If not loading:

- If loggedIn then render your routes,
- If not, render login page and nothing else. Also change the url to /login.

Comment: I'm not able to hit my OAuth Login-Callback route with this pattern

Comment: Maybe I could put the logincallback route in this wrapper.

Comment: You could follow sth like that for sure